# Error While Creating Action in Sales Quotes Screen CR304500

Tags: acumatica

I have created an Action in Sales Quotes Screen to create my "Forecast Document" (Customize Screen) and get the Forecast Document Nbr back into the Sales Quote Screen in the field "Forecast". Though the below code is working absolutely fine in other modules Like SO, PO and ARInvoice. As the Error says "Forecast document cannot be found in the system" which is not so, I can see the same document in the Forecast Document Screen. Following is my code:

```
#region Create Forecast

        public PXAction<CRQuote> createForecast;
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Create Forecast Doc", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Update)]
        [PXProcessButton(CommitChanges = true)]
        public IEnumerable CreateForecast(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            CRQuote currentQuote = this.Base.Quote.Current;

            if (currentQuote != null && currentQuote.QuoteNbr != null)
            {
                CRQuote quoteX = PXSelect<CRQuote, Where<CRQuote.quoteNbr, Equal<Current<CRQuote.quoteNbr>>>>.Select(this.Base, currentQuote.QuoteNbr);
                if (quoteX != null)
                {
                    CreateForecastMethod(quoteX);
                }
            }

            return adapter.Get();
        }

        ////PrivateMethod Create Forecast.
        public virtual void CreateForecastMethod(CRQuote fHeader)
        {
            //Base.Actions.PressSave();
            bool var_forecastCreated = false;
            bool erroroccured = false;
            string ErrMsg = "";

            ForecastEntry forecastGraphObject = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ForecastEntry>();
            ForecastHeader forecastHeaderObject = new ForecastHeader();
            QuoteMaint currGRPH = PXGraph.CreateInstance<QuoteMaint>();
            var Extension = this.Base.GetExtension<SOOrderEntry_Extension>();
            try
            {
                forecastHeaderObject.RefDocNbr = fHeader.QuoteNbr;
                forecastHeaderObject.RefDocTotal = fHeader.CuryProductsAmount;
                forecastHeaderObject.DocType = "FORECAST";
                forecastHeaderObject.ForecastType = "FORECAST";

                forecastHeaderObject = forecastGraphObject.ForecastH.Insert(forecastHeaderObject);
                forecastGraphObject.ForecastH.Current = forecastHeaderObject;
                forecastGraphObject.Actions.PressSave();

                var_forecastCreated = true;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                erroroccured = true;
                ErrMsg = e.Message;
            }

            if (erroroccured)
            {
                // Acuminator disable once PX1053 ConcatenationPriorLocalization [Justification]
                throw new PXException("Cannot create Forecast Document: " + ErrMsg);
            }
            else
            {
                if (var_forecastCreated)
                {
                    CRQuote QORD = Base.Quote.Current;
                    CRQuoteExt xQuoteExt = PXCache<CRQuote>.GetExtension<CRQuoteExt>(QORD);
                    xQuoteExt.UsrForecastInvoice = forecastHeaderObject.RefNbr;
                    Base.Quote.Update(QORD); //this line gives the error
                    Base.Save.Press();
                  
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion
```

[image]

Comment: Assuming that screen actually exists, do you have access rights to it?

Comment: What are the DAC attributes decorating that field? The error message could be coming from a selector BQL query that filters out more documents than the original screen.

Comment: Please also remember that CRQuote is a Projection so make sure you have also extended the Standalone.CRQuote DAC as well and have used BqlField on your custom field definitions for CRQuote.

Comment: @BrianStevens, Yes i have access rights to that screen. Thanks.

Comment: @HuguesBeauséjour : You are absolutely correct, the BQL in the selector was filtering out more documents than the original screen. Its rectified now. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @cbetabeta : Yes i am aware of that, I have the Standalone.CRQuote DAC as well. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error document 'X' cannot be found in the system often occurs because the selector attribute can't get the record.

The first troubleshooting step is to check if the record exists in the database.

If the selector filters out the target record you will get this error. You can remove the selector attribute filter (joins and where clauses) to check if this is the root cause of the error.

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search2<APRegister.refNbr,
                LeftJoin<APInvoice, On<APRegister.docType, Equal<APInvoice.docType>,
                    And<APRegister.refNbr, Equal<APInvoice.refNbr>>>>,
                Where<APRegister.docType, Equal<Optional<APRegister.docType>>,
                    And<APInvoiceJCExt.isJointPayees, NotEqual<True>,
                    And<IsSchedulable<APRegister>>>>>)]
```

To debug the selector filter, use Acumatica Request Profiler to obtain the final SQL request sent to database.